# Set Memory Limit in Tensorflow for CPU

Tags: tensorflow, cpu, memory-limit

I am using Tensorflow - cpu mode for one of deep learning project.
In Tensorflow, i am not able to set memory limit for the project.
Currently memory allocated by Tensorflow :

[name: "/device:**CPU:0**"

device_type: "**CPU**"

memory_limit: **268435456**

locality {
}

incarnation: 12554950994086873035
]

How this memory limit can be changed?
Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a way to limit the directly limit the CPU memory usage, but you can specify the cores to use: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4314